# Array shuffle java

Tags: java

i have to problems trying to shuffle the values of an array and returning them. I have to ask the user if it wants to shuffle using a loop, if the users answers "y" then display the shuffle values if the answers is "n" then get out of the loop. I would appreciate any help.

Here is what i have so far.

Main class

```
package lab4b;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4B
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int size = 15;
        char q = 'y';
        boolean flag = false;

        Shuffler myShuffler = new Shuffler(size);

        myShuffler.display();
        System.out.println();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Do you wish to shuffle this numbers? ");
        String input2 = input.next();


        myShuffler.shuffle();
        myShuffler.display();
        System.out.printf("Do you wish to shuffle this numbers? ");

        input.close();


    }
}
```

Shuffler class

```
package lab4b;

import java.util.Random;

public class Shuffler
{

    private int[] data;

    public Shuffler(int size)
    {
        data = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i + 1;
        }

    }

    public void shuffle()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random(15);

            int second = r.nextInt(15) + 1;
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[second];
            data[second] = temp;
        }

    }

    public void display()
    {

        String values = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            if (i < 15)
            {
                values += (i + 1);
                if (i < 14)
                {
                    values += ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Array Contents: %s \n", values);


    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the _exact_ problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `...get out of the loop...` I don't see any loop besides the one in the shuffler, which probably isn't the one you mean.

Comment: I need help prompting the user using a loop and the shuffle the numbers. How do i tell the shuffle method to do its work when the user answers y, and get out of the loop when the user enters n.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would code the Shuffle logic yourself.  Java Collections has a built-in Shuffle:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List).  There is one that takes a Random too:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List, java.util.Random)

Turn your Array into a List, let Collections shuffle it, turn the list back to an array.

Comment: No need to turn the list back to an array. Simply wrap the array inside a list using Arrays.asList(), shuffle the list, and it will shuffle the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a part that might fail:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  Random r = new Random(15);

  int second = r.nextInt(15) + 1;
  int temp = data[i];
  data[i] = data[second];
  data[second] = temp;
}
```

You're creating a second index in the range [1,15] but what if the `data` array is smaller or bigger? If smaller you'd get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if bigger, you'd always swap the current element with those at indices 1 to 15.

In that part you're listing the indices instead of the values and only up to 15 of them:

```
if (i < 15) //what if data was bigger than 15 elements?
{
  values += (i + 1); //you might want to use data[i] instead of (1 + 1) here.
  if (i < 14)
  {
    values += ", ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for replying but maybe I was not very clear. My array contains values 1 ... 15. I have to display the values in order then ask the user to shuffle. Here is an output example.      Array Contains: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? y  Array contains: 5 12 7 10 6 9 15 1 13 3 4 11 14 2 8 if user enters n get out of loop.

Comment: @PedroIt well what values the array contains is somewhat irrelvant, the problem is you're mixing values and indices as well as dynamic and hard coded array lengths which is likely to produce errors.